# error in comparing current path with capybara and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a link in my comments view for replying to a comment like this:

```rb
<%= link_to t('.reply', :default => t("helpers.links.reply")), new_story_comment_path(comment.story, parent_id: comment)%>
```

Some part of the test is like this:

```rb
  it "replies to a comment" do
    comment = FactoryGirl.create :comment, story_id: story.id, user_id: user.id
    visit story_path story
    save_and_open_page
    click_link "reply"
    current_path.should eq(new_story_comment_path story.id, parent_id: comment.id)
    ...
  end
```

I get this error:

```rb
  1) Comments replies to a comment
     Failure/Error: current_path.should eq(new_story_comment_path story.id, parent_id: comment.id)

       expected: "/stories/1/comments/new?parent_id=1"
            got: "/stories/1/comments/new"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/requests/comments_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I checked the page with save_and_open_page and the link is correct:

```rb
file:///stories/1/comments/new?parent_id=1
```

I also checked the test.log file and I can see this line:

```rb
Started GET "/stories/1/comments/new?parent_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-02 21:05:57
```

Why i get this error each time, while it should be correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

current_path only includes the path and does not include the URL parameters. You will likely need to use current_url to get the entire URL.

Comment: Thanks :) I had to change all paths to url.